# What magic do Box and Arc use to allow casting to trait objects? Is there a way to do this with my own types?

Tags: rust, traits

In Rust, you can cast from `Arc/Box/Rc<T>` to `Arc/Box/Rc<dyn Trait>` using some sort of compiler magic accessed with the `as` keyword. Is there a way to opt into this magic for a user-defined type, or are `Arc` and `Box` special cases?

Attempting this naively results in an error:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

struct X<T: ?Sized> {
    t: Box<T>,
}

impl <T> X<T> {
    pub fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self { t: Box::new(t) }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new("123".to_owned()) as Arc<dyn AsRef<str>>;
    let x = Box::new("123".to_owned()) as Box<dyn AsRef<str>>;
    let x = X::new("123".to_owned()) as X<dyn AsRef<str>>;
}
```

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `X<String>` as `X<dyn AsRef<str>>`
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |     let x = X::new("123".to_owned()) as X<dyn AsRef<str>>;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79c969fe9bdca1d20637c33436e55cda).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but only on nightly (and this feature won't be stabilized as-is). This magic is working via [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html):

```rust
#![feature(coerce_unsized, unsize)]

impl<T: ?Sized + std::marker::Unsize<U>, U: ?Sized> std::ops::CoerceUnsized<X<U>> for X<T> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a middle-way solution for stable Rust.

As Chayim said, the "magic" you look for is reserved for `Box`, `Rc` etc. in stable Rust. A clever workaround is then leaving the magic to these structures. Extending your example, you can define a `new_boxed` function that does not take care of boxing the content of your structure. Instead, it receives an already boxed element:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized> X<T> {
    pub fn new_boxed(t: Box<T>) -> Self {
        Self { t }
    }
}
```

Now, we can leave `Box` do the magic for us and get trait objects of our custom structs:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let x = Box::new("123".to_owned()) as Box<dyn AsRef<str>>;
    let x = X::new_boxed(x) as X<dyn AsRef<str>>;
}
```

Here you have a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a065f97a30556c01ea1c03876f9d4a9d). I know it is not exactly what you were looking for, but at least it can be used in stable Rust. Hope you find this alternative useful.